# Can git be installed and git commands be used by using webpack

Tags: webpack, gitlab, git-clone, adobe-xd

I am creating my own plugin on Adobe XD and i need to use Git command to clone or pull (By using SSH key) the files from my git repo. Whether it can be done. Kindly provide me with a solution(cloning should be done by webpack).

Answer (score 0):

Webpack itself doesn't have any git related plugin that you can use. However, you can write your own wrapper script over Webpack and install one of the Node.js git client like [git](https://www.npmjs.com/package/git) or [simple-git](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-git) which you can use.

Writing a [Webpack plugin](https://webpack.js.org/contribute/writing-a-plugin/) or custom loader is not very hard. This is generally the practice followed by framework CLI wrappers like `create-react-app`, `vue-cli` or `angular-cli`.

To use, Webpack in a custom Node.js script, use this [official guide](https://webpack.js.org/api/node/).

Comment: Thank you and can i get any help or similar code to do that...  Is there any link to proceed with

Comment: @Naresh, There is no link as such. I have added links in the answer that can help you get started. Please consider the answer as accepted if it addresses your question